# Every finite subset of $\Gamma$ is consistent implies $\Gamma$ is consistent

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

> **Thm:** If every finite subset of $\Gamma$ is consistent then $\Gamma$ is consistent.

My notes claims that it can be implied from compactness of $\vdash$. Meaning: If $\Gamma \vdash A$ then there's a finite subset $\Delta\in\Gamma$ such that $\Delta\vdash A$.

I don't see how it explains the theorem above.

I'd be glad for an explanation.

Comment: A set of statements is inconsistent if it implies a contradiction or `false`.

Comment: I think you mean $\models$ rather than $\vdash$ (it is trivial that if there is a deduction of $A$ from $\Gamma$ then there is a deduction of $A$ from a finite subset of $\Gamma$).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose to the contrary that $\Gamma$ is not consistent. Then there is a sentence $\varphi$ such that $(\varphi \land \lnot\varphi)$ is a theorem of $\Gamma$. Then by Compactness $(\varphi \land \lnot\varphi)$ is provable from some finite subset $\Delta$ of $\Gamma$. It follows that some finite subset of $\Gamma$ is not consistent.

Comment: @LiorGolan: You are welcome.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Prove the contrapositive. Suppose that $\Gamma$ is inconsistent: in particular, then for some $\alpha$, $\Gamma\vdash \alpha$ and $\Gamma\vdash \neg\alpha$. Use compactness to find finite $\Delta_1, \Delta_2$ such that $\Delta_1\vdash \alpha$ and $\Delta_2\vdash \neg\alpha$. Can you find an inconsistent finite subset in terms of $\Delta_1$ and $\Delta_2$?

Comment: Take $\Delta_1\cup\Delta_2.$ Then it is a finite subset of $\Gamma$ which is inconsistent.